# Change TextField (MUI) background color when data present

Tags: material-ui, textfield, styled-components

Using the 'styled' MUI component, with theme, a TextField component has been created.

When the TextField has no data (ie, empty), below styles were used to render the background as a custom-grey color:

> ```
> '& .MuiInputBase-root': {
>   backgroundColor: theme.palette.background.grey01,
>   height: '40px'
> },
> ```

This backgroundColor needs to change (to white) when data has been entered into the TextField. Not just 'on focus', but if data is present (ie, TextField is not-empty) the white-background must persist; however, if user deletes/removes data (ie, TextField is emptied by user), backgroundColor needs to go back to custom-grey.

From Chrome Inspect, was able to track down the relevant classes (including .Mui-focused):

```
MuiOutlinedInput-root MuiInputBase-root MuiInputBase-colorPrimary Mui-Focused MuiInputBase-formControl css-1byr8j2-MuiInputBase-root-MuiOutlinedInput-root
```

Have reviewed MUI documentation at https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#use-rulename-to-reference-a-local-rule-within-the-same-style-sheet but unable to determine a way to know when value is populated / empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

I had overlooked the easiest and most elegant solution.

```js
const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  .MuiInputBase-root {
    background-color: ${({theme, value}) => 
      !value && theme.palette.background.grey01};
  }
`
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you.

The component already receives 'value' as a prop. So, was able to use value.length to determine backgroundColor to be grey or white. And, it works !!

Comment: @jsN00b Perfect! Sorry, I kind of suck at SC, but glad to have been of help! 